# Querying sum of multiple aggregate columns (without groupBy)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, group-by, laravel-query-builder

I have a `transactions` table and I'm trying to get the total of each type.

To simply put it looks like this

| id | type | credit_movement |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | top_up | 10000 |
| 2 | fee | -50 |
| 3 | deduct | -1000 |

I am trying to get sum of each type to show as a report.

```
top_up: 10000
fee: 50
deduct: 1000
net_expense: 9850 [top_up - deduct - fee]
```

```
$types = [
   'top_up' => ['top_up'],
   'deduct' => ['deduct'],
   'fee' => ['fee'],
   'net_expense' => ['top_up', 'deduct', 'fee'], 
];

$query = DB::table('transactions');

foreach ($types as $type => $fields) {

    $query->selectSub(function ($query) use ($fields) {
        return $query->selectRaw('SUM(credit_movement)')->whereIn('type', $fields);
    }, $type);

};

$results = $query->get();
```

When I do this, I get:

> 1140 In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'project.transactions.type'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by..

When I change my `database.mysql.strict = false`, it works; however I want to make it work properly without needing to change the mysql config.

As of my understanding, this error indicates that I am only selecting aggregated columns, but in my case I don't actually want to `groupBy()` anything as this is just reports.

If I try to `groupBy('type')` it returns everything grouped by type, but the queries are only run within that group.

```
{
 0: {
    top_up: 10000,
    deduct: 0,
    fee: 0,
    net_expense: 10000
 }
 1: {
    top_up: 0,
    deduct: -1000,
    fee: 0,
    net_expense: -1000
 },
 // etc...
}
```

---

Is there a way to obtain without changing `strict` to false?

```
{
 0 => {
    top_up: 10000,
    deduct: -1000,
    fee: -50,
    net_expense: 9850
 }
}
```

Comment: If your where clause is limiting results to always be just 1 type; don't select the type in your.... select statement... you already know the value since you limited by it; so you don't need to select it and you then won't need to group by it.  I'm not sure why you wouldn't just get all the values/results in one trip to the database and iterate though the results instead of executing multiple queries; but that's your design.  Strict SQL requires all non-aggregated columns to appear in a group by.  So simply don't select it.  This works because you already know it's value from the where clause.

Comment: have you tried to add ->select('type')  ..... then groupBy('type'); just add type in select and groupBy

Comment: @xQbert Laravel's `selectSub()` doesn't execute multiple queries which is why I chose this. When I have +1m records, I would rather not save all of those in a variable and calculate in the runtime. That's why I'd rather have mysql calculate the sums and return the result directly.

Comment: @OMR Yes, I tried and it's written in the OP: _"If I try to groupBy('type')..."_. This returns 1 object per type and only includes that type's results. Which is not too bad but not ideal either because if it can do it, the desired outcome is almost there too.

Comment: @senty  from a Pure SQL Standpoint: `Select type, sum(Credit_movement) x from transactions group by type` gets you all teh types: but if you're iterating through them  then you don't need type.  `Select sum(credit_Movement) x from transactions where type = 'fee'`  or get them all `SELECT type, sum(credit_movement) x from transactions where type in ('your list') group by type` then iterate though the types locally as you get the data you needed no more, no less and the DB did all the math.

Comment: we can modify the group by on the last sql statement to be `group by grouping sets ((type),())` to handle the fact you want a sum of all the types selected aggregated together.  now as this is mySQL... it may be rollup instead of grouping sets.. I get those mixed up with different RDBMS and would have to look it up.  yeah it would be `GROUP BY Type with ROLLUP` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: @xQbert Thanks - I understand your point and it makes sense now (which is similar to R4ncid's answer too). I'll go with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly this might be very easy but again I might have not understood it right.

```
$result = DB::table('transactions')->selectRaw('type, SUM(credit_movement) as sum')->groupBy('status')->get();
```

This should return something like this:

| type | sum |
| --- | --- |
| fee | -5656 |
| topup | 8758 |
| deduct | -7625 |

For the total sum you can just do it in php which would make it easier

```
$net = $result->sum('sum'); // equals -5656+8758-7625
```

Hope this helps and let me know if I am wrong about it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach is in the final column that is the sum of the other 3 so you can't use SUM because you don't have a column to group.
You could use a subquery but I think that the best solution is to add a little elaboration of the raw data that you get from a simpler query.

```
$query = DB::table('transactions')
  ->selectRaw('type, SUM(credit_movement) AS movements')
  ->groupBy('type');

$results = array_reduce($query->get(), function(array $res, array $value){
    $res[$array['type']] = $array['movements'];
    return $res;
}, []);

$results['net_expense'] = array_sum($results);
```

Comment: Thanks. In this case, you won't even need to add a `selectSub()`, you can directly chain to the query itself. I'll go with this solution - thanks again

Comment: Yeah sorry I really never used laravel query builder so I just copied some of your code...I'm more a doctrine guy myself